UI Tests for Android Auth0 authentication
Has anyone successfully implemented UI tests for an Android app that utilizes Auth0 web authentication?
I'm currently working on testing our hybrid Android app's Auth0 integration and am having trouble accessing objects on the Chrome browser's web view with Compose/Espresso UI Tests.
Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
